# Random selection from datasource

Tags: matlab, dataset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [randperm subset of random m-by-n matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781542/randperm-subset-of-random-m-by-n-matrix)

When trying to randomly select 1000 rows from a dataset "fulldata" I get an error, im not very sure how its done in matlab but this is what I tryed:

```
data = datasample(fulldata,6,1000)
```

The fulldata is 490256x6 and I want to select 1000 random rows from this data. In matlab its throwing the error

```
??? Undefined function or method 'datasample' for input arguments
of type 'double'.

Error in ==> randomselection at 44
data = datasample(fulldata,6,1000)
```

Comment: your error normally means that `datasample` doesn't exist, it's not on your current path or you are using it with the wrong type of arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instead to something like this to get it without relying on datasample:

```
pointsToPick = 1000;  %# Numbers to pick
rVec = randperm(N);   %# Random permutation of datapoint indices (N=490256 in your case)  

randomSample = fulldata(rVec(1:pointsToPick),:); %# Random sample
```